# What is the difference in memory utilization between require and load in ruby

Tags: ruby, load, require

In Ruby both require and load are used for same purpose then what should I use to ensure minimum memory in my ruby code

Comment: `require` and `load` are **not** identical. In general, you should always use `require` - unless you have a specific reason to need `load`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about minimum memory but as Tom said those two methods are different. `load` is to execute code / script. `require` is to import libraries. Also, that’s why `require` tries only once to load each file, while `load` executes the file again every time you call it.

Comment: "Executing a script" and "importing a library" are exactly the same thing in Ruby.

Comment: Well yes, they are very similar. The difference is subtle.